# Importing service layer to child component Issue

Tags: angular

I have written a service layer which calls rest api to return me some data.
If I import that service in app.component.ts , it seems to be working fine but I have created child component i.e. user-credentials.component.ts and **if i import that service layer , I get error :-**

**ERROR in D:/Projects/Angular 2/AuditUserAccess/src/app/user-credentials/user-credentials.component.ts (2,31): Cannot find module './user-services/user-data.service'.**

**This is how i am importing my service layer file in both parent and child component :-**

```
 import {UserDataService} from './user-services/user-data.service';
```

**This is my Project Structure :-**

1. **./app/app.component**
2. **./app/user-credentials/user-credentials.component**
3. **./app/user-services/user-data.service i.e. UserDataService**

Following is my UserDataService service component

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Headers, Http, RequestOptions,Response  } from 
  '@angular/http';
  import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

  import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';



  @Injectable()
  export class UserDataService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  private applicationName = '/getAllApplications';

  getApplicationNames() : Observable<any> {

     // ...using get request
     return this.http.get(this.applicationName)
                     .map((res:Response) => res.json())
                     .catch((error:any) => 
     Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));

 }


}
```

**Would want to know how to give proper path to the service layer or how to change project structure if that need be , so that i can work with it.**

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? `Http` was changed to `HttpClient` in Angular v4.3. The RxJS operator import and usage was changed in v6. Regarding your specific error ... often just existing the editor and opening it again solves this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add it to providers section of the app module in exports.